# Bulk invoke AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to call AWS Lambda hundreds of thousands times, with different parameters. Is there a way to somehow execute it in bulk, passing a long list of parameters or e.g. a path to an S3 object with one line per payload?

Comment: Is it going to be `one time only` or `repetitive` one ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all of the parameters through an Amazon's SQS. You can specify the batch size (i.e the number of messages that would be sent simultaneously in a group). Only issue is that the maximum number of messages sent at once is 10. Although, this should still be more efficient than processing them one by one. Alternatively you can also encode all the parameters within a single message, just keep in mind that maximum message size is 256KB.

Answer (score 1):

A common technique is:

- Create an **Amazon SQS queue**
- Configure the queue to **trigger your AWS Lambda function**
- Send messages to the queue. Each message would contain a set of **input parameters** that will be used by the Lambda function.

The format of the parameters is your choice because you will need to write code in the Lambda function to retrieve the parameters from the `event` record that is passed to the handler function.

You can configure a **batch size** which controls how many messages are sent to the Lambda function. You can set it to `1` to process a single message, or make it bigger and have the Lambda function loop through the messages that have been provided.

I recommend that you **test the process with just a few messages** before putting all the messages in the queue.

See:

- [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)
- [AWS Lambda function scaling - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to call AWS Lambda hundreds of thousands times, with different parameters.

for this you can use [aws EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) where you can schedule a lambda as per your convenience using cron expression ( for fine granularity), or if you want to send events from different [aws sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html) or third party that can also be done using an event pattern.

> after selecting target as aws lambda you  can [configure input](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutTargets.html) as constant **jsontext,matched event, part of matched event or Input transformer**

note:- eventbroidge also allows to retry policy and deal letter queue